# How can I call the retrofit service that is nested and retrieve the data correctly? [retrofit2]

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying fetch data from API using retrofit2.

The model of my data is this:

Corporations.class

```
public class Corporations{

Company company = new Company();
ArrayList<Departments> departments = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<OfficeLocations> officeLocations = new ArrayList<>();

public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(Company company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public ArrayList<Departments> getDepartments() {
    return departments;
}

public void setDepartments(ArrayList<Departments> departments) {
    this.departments = departments;
}

public ArrayList<OfficeLocations> getofficeLocations() {
    return officeLocations;
}

public void setofficeLocations(ArrayList<OfficeLocations> officeLocations) {
    this.officeLocations = officeLocations;
}

public class Company {
    Integer CompanyId;
    String CompanyName;

    public Company() {
    }

    public Integer getCompanyId() {
        return CompanyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(Integer companyId) {
        this.CompanyId = companyId;
    }

    public String CompanyName() {
        return CompanyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String CompanyName) {
        this.CompanyName = CompanyName;
    }
}

public class Departments {
    Integer CompanyId, DepartmentId;
    String DepartmentName;

    public Departments() {
    }

    public Integer getCompanyId() {
        return CompanyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(Integer CompanyId) {
        CompanyId = CompanyId;
    }

    public Integer getDepartmentId() {
        return DepartmentId;
    }

    public void setDepartmentId(Integer DepartmentId) {
        this.DepartmentId = DepartmentId;
    }

    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return DepartmentName;
    }

    public void setDepartmentName(String DepartmentName) {
        this.DepartmentName = DepartmentName;
    }
}

public class OfficeLocations {
    Integer LocationId, CompanyId;
    String LocationName;

    public OfficeLocations() {

    }

    public Integer getLocationId() {
        return LocationId;
    }

    public void setLocationId(Integer LocationId) {
        this.LocationId = LocationId;
    }

    public String getLocationName() {
        return fundId;
    }

    public void setLocationName(String LocationName) {
        this.LocationName = LocationName;
    }

    public Integer getCompanyId() {
        return CompanyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(Integer CompanyId) {
        CompanyId = CompanyId;
    }

}
}
```

This is my helper class where I am calling the retrofit service:

```
public class Helper {

public interface CorporationsHelperCallbacks() {
    void setCompanies(ArrayList<Corporations.Company> companyList);        
}

public interface DepartmentHelperCallbacks(){
    void setDepartments(ArrayList<Corporations.Departments> deptList);
    void setLocations(ArrayList<Corporations.OfficeLocations> locationList);
}

public void getCompanies(String apiKey, @Nullable final CorporationsHelperCallbacks callback){
    Call<ArrayList<Corporations.Company>> call = apiInterface.getSolutionProducts(apiKey);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<MySolutionsProductModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Corporations.Company>> call, Response<ArrayList<Corporations.Company>> response) {
            try {
                ArrayList list = response.body();
                callback.setCompanies(list);
            } catch (Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(context,ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Corporations.Company>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

public void getCompanyData(int companyId, String apiKey, @Nullable final CorporationsHelperCallbacks callback){
    Call<ArrayList<Corporations>> call = apiInterface.getSolutionProducts(comapanyId, apiKey);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Corporations>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Corporations>> call, Response<ArrayList<Corporations>> response) {
            try {
                ArrayList list = response.body();
                callback.setDepartments(list.getDepartments());
                callback.setLocations(list.getLocations());
            } catch (Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(context,ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Corporations>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

And this is how I need to call the retrofit method:

```
public void getData{
    helper.getCompanies(apiKey, new Helper.CorporationsHelperCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void setCompanies(final ArrayList<Corporations.Company> companyList) {
            CorporationsModel corporations;
            for (int i = 0; i < companyList.size(); i++) {
                corporations = new CorporationsModel()
                corporations.getcompanyList().setCompanyId(companyList.get(i).getCompanyId());
                corporations.getcompanyList().setCompanyName(companyList.get(i).getCompanyName());

                helper.getCompanyData(companyList.get(i).getCompanyId(), apiKey, new Helper.DepartmentHelperCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void setDepartments(ArrayList<Corporations.Departments> deptList) {
                        if (deptList.size() > 0) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < deptList.size(); j++) {
                                corporations.getDepartments().get(j).setDepartmentId(deptList.get(j).getDepartmentId());
                                corporations.getDepartments().get(j).setDepartmentName(deptList.get(j).getDepartmentName());
                                corporations.getDepartments().get(j).setCompanyId(deptList.get(j).getCompanyId());

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setLocations(ArrayList<Corporations.OfficeLocations> locationList) {
                        if (locationList.size() > 0) {
                            for (int k = 0; k < locationList.size(); k++) {
                                corporations.getofficeLocations().get(k).setLocationId(locationList.get(k).getLocationId()));
                                corporations.getofficeLocations().get(k).setLocationName(locationList.get(k).getLocationName()));
                                corporations.getofficeLocations().get(k).setCompanyId(locationList.get(k).getCompanyId()));

                            }
                        }
                    }

                companyList.add(corporations);//this is a global variable
            }
            String str = gson.toJson(companyList);
            sharedPreferenceEditor.putString("companyList",str);
            sharedPreferenceEditor.commit();

        }
    });
}
```

I need to execute the above call and store the list of company datas in SharedPreference. But due to the asynchronous nature of retrofit, the inner service are called but without the data is added to the list, the shared preference is executed. The data needs to be stored in this format because this is how api has been designed.

How can I do it correctly?? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you used a database. You would just update the object with the departments and the locations.

If you really want/need to use the shared prefs, you need to put this block

```
    String str = gson.toJson(companyList);
    sharedPreferenceEditor.putString("companyList",str);
    sharedPreferenceEditor.commit();
```

inside the locations callback `setLocations()` on the final iteration, `i == companyList.size() - 1`

Comment: Are there no other elegant way of doing it?

Comment: @vinitpradhan18 there is, use a database. that way once you create the companies in the DB you can just update fields (locations, departments) when you need to

Comment: I tried to use database before. But it was way too much work. I do not need to store this data in app. I just need to pass it from one fragment to another for a series of operations. This in only one data model. I have plenty of other models. So creating a table for each model would be too much work. Let me know if there are better ways of approaching it.